# What command can be used to force release everything in swap partition back to memory?

Tags: linux, swap

What command can be used to force release everything in swap partition back to memory ?

Presume that I have enough memory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/103871/46754):

> You can also clear your swap by running `swapoff -a` and then `swapon -a` as root instead of rebooting to achieve the same effect.

Thus:

```
$ free -tm
...
Swap:         6439        196       6243
...
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo swapon -a
$ free -tm
...
Swap:         6439          0       6439
...
```

As noted in a comment, if you don't have enough memory, `swapoff` will result in "out of memory" errors and on the kernel killing processes to recover RAM.

Comment: Explaining this further, if you don't have enough available RAM `swapoff` will result in *out of memory* errors and the kernel will start killing processes to recover some. Use this with caution.

Comment: Better hope so; linux behaves pretty hilariously when you run out of memory with no active swap at *all*...

Answer (score 4):

As noted, simply deactivating all swap will cause the kernel to start killing things if it doesn't have enough free memory.  If you wish to avoid that, create a second set of swap first.  Then:

```
swapon /second/swap/device && swapoff /first/swap/device 
swapon /first/swap/device && swapoff /second/swap/device
```

This will still swap in everything, but if there's not enough space it'll get shifted to the second swap device instead of randomly killing things.  Then just shift it all back.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
sudo bash -c 'swapoff -a && swapon -a'
```